# how to assign associative array as images php

Tags: php, arrays

I am creating a retail website for a project.

How do I make it so that the arrays will display images like a real retail website? For example, 4 images neatly in a line row after row.

```
<?php

$navItems = array (
                array(
                    'slug'  => "index.php",
                    'title' => "Home"
                     ),
                array(
                    'slug'  => "menu.php",
                    'title' => "Menu"
                     ),
                array(
                    'slug'  => "contact.php",
                    'title' => "Contact"
                     ),
                );
$menuItems = array(
                "club-sandwich" => array(
                    "name"  => "Club Sandwich",
                    "price" => 11,
                    "blurb" => "Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet fatback landjaeger ullamco pariatur. Nostrud laboris et, duis drumstick eiusmod kevin ut aliquip. Filet mignon short ribs tenderloin short loin kielbasa non pork chop aliqua. Jerky shank tri-tip capicola, non andouille tenderloin cupidatat turducken meatball pork beef eu shoulder jowl.",
                    "drink" => "Club Soda"  
                ),
                "dill-salmon" => array(
                    "name"  => "Lemon &amp; Dill Salmon",
                    "price" => 18,
                    "blurb" => "Pork belly tempor ground round qui exercitation, jowl leberkas sed voluptate excepteur jerky. Reprehenderit veniam cow, quis in ribeye andouille eu pastrami eiusmod exercitation dolor.",
                    "drink" => "Fancy Wine" 
                ),
                "super-salad" => array(
                    "name"  => "The Super Salad<sup>&reg;</sup>",
                    "price" => 34,
                    "blurb" => "Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.",
                    "drink" => "Jug o' Water"   
                ),
                "mexican-barbacoa" => array(
                    "name"  => "Mexican Barbacoa",
                    "price" => 23,
                    "blurb" => "I love fruitcake danish caramels. Tart danish pastry liquorice chocolate cake fruitcake. Bear claw gingerbread muffin I love apple pie apple pie tiramisu brownie chocolate. Sweet roll cotton candy cupcake gingerbread gummies jelly-o. Muffin I love croissant I love jelly-o brownie jelly beans. Toffee I love pastry.",
                    "drink" => "Beer with a lime"   
                ),
             );
?>
```

I thought to assign the image as part of the array but it did not work.

```
<?php

$navItems = array (
                array(
                    'slug'  => "index.php",
                    'title' => "Home"
                     ),
                array(
                    'slug'  => "menu.php",
                    'title' => "Menu"
                     ),
                array(
                    'slug'  => "contact.php",
                    'title' => "Contact"
                     ),
                );
$menuItems = array(
                "club-sandwich" => array(
                    "name"  => "Club Sandwich",
                    "price" => 11,
                    "blurb" => "Bacon iort loin kielbasa non pork chop aliqua. Jerky shank tri-tip capicola, non andouille tenderloin cupidatat turducken meatball pork beef eu shoulder jowl.",
                    "drink" => "Club Soda"
                    "image" => <img src="hr.png">   
                ),
                "dill-salmon" => array(
                    "name"  => "Lemon &amp; Dill Salmon",
                    "price" => 18,
                    "blurb" => "Pork belly tempor ground round qui exercitation, jowl leberkas sed voluptate excepteur jerky. Reprehenderit veniam cow, quis in ribeye andouille eu pastrami eiusmod exercitation dolor.",
                    "drink" => "Fancy Wine"
                    "image" => <img src = "hr.png">
                ),
                "super-salad" => array( 
                    "name"  => "The Super Salad<sup>&reg;</sup>",
                    "price" => 34,
                    "blurb" => "Gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato. Dandelion cucumber earthnut pea peanut soko zucchini.",
                    "drink" => "Jug o' Water"
                    "image" => <img src = "hr.png">
                ),
                "mexican-barbacoa" => array(    
                    "name"  => "Mexican Barbacoa",
                    "price" => 23,
                    "blurb" => "I love fruitcake danish caramels. Tart danish pastry liquorice chocolate cake fruitcake. Bear claw gingerbread muffin I love apple pie apple pie tiramisu brownie chocolate. Sweet roll cotton candy cupcake gingerbread gummies jelly-o. Muffin I love croissant I love jelly-o brownie jelly beans. Toffee I love pastry.",
                    "drink" => "Beer with a lime"
                    "image" => <img src = "hr.png">
                ),
             );
?>
```

Comment: `"image" => <image src = "hr.png">` is not valid PHP syntax.  Just send the URI, and generate the `<image>` tag when you render the array: `"image" => "hr.png"`, then `<image src="<?= $item['image'] ?>">`

Comment: oh is there no way to get the images from my folders instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: i have actually downloaded all my images into a folder. am i not allowed to get the image from the folder instead?

Answer (score 0):

Use the html Image tag. Insert in your array the url to the Image and the print all.
  `<Img src="<?php echo $array['image_url']; ?>">` 
If you want to get images from your folder simply put all the images in a directory, and then list all the files(that will be the images) and save  their paths in your array and do what i told you before.
   `<?php $filenames=scan_dir($path); ?>`

Comment: sorry i am new to php i do not know how to make the url or put the image in a directory

Comment: use what you want to put images on a directory (even ftp).